# Some users experience White blank screen for React deployment but apple users dont

Tags: reactjs, deployment, typeerror

Anyone know why some users, specifically those using microsoft products , see a white screen for my React deployment? My deployment works and renders fine on my devices, mobile and standard.  I have specified the homepage URL inside package.json ..

The error code for those experiencing the white screen is as followed

````
at Module.<anonymous>(index.js:13)
at l ((index):1)
at Object.(anonymous>(main.2a705d2.chunk.js:1)
at l ((index):1)
2:22
at t ((index):1)
at Array.r[as push]((index:1)
at main.2a705d2.chunk.js:1```

MY GITHUB REPO: 
https://github.com/dreamingofcode/Travelly

deployment:
https://nervous-lovelace-0d5b8e.netlify.app/
````

Answer (score 0):

Its pointing right to your error `index.js:13` anyone without the redux devtools installed its going to fail. That is not the correct way to add in the dev tools. https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension